# backbone view not displaying values from model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am writing a very simple backbone model/view display. Basically there is a json field called shortDescription, and it should be displayed into a . However my code is not showing empty no matter what value I set inside the view.

Here is the code, where am I doing wrong?

html code:

```
<div id="itemDetailContainer"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="itemDetailTemplate">
    < h3 > <% shortDescription %> < /h3>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
ItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {}
});

ItemDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.$el = $("#itemDetailContainer");
        this.template = _.template($("#itemDetailTemplate").html());
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var it = new ItemModel({"shortDescription": "short"});
var v = new ItemDetailView({model: it});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cpn3g/886/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I should use <%= %> instead of <% %>.

Syntax mistake :(